# How to insert space after each number in a string MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.1

I have a string and I need to insert a space after each number.

e.g. `Ctn/10Btl/100ml` to be converted it to `Ctn/10 Btl/100 ml`.

Can you help me how to query to insert space after number?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That's not a space after each character. It's just after each number.

Comment: What version of MySQL? With 8.x you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE()`

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks, my MySQL version is 10.x.

Comment: That's a MariaDB version.

Comment: Specific MariaDB version please. Some function in version 10.2 and above are not available in version 10.1 or lower.

Comment: yes, it is MaridDB (version - 10.1.38-MariaDB) . sry, my mistake. @fadlikidd

Comment: Its ok @Zaw , it seems like MariaDB has introduced [REGEXP_REPLACE since v 10.0.5](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/). Now, it's just a matter of figuring out how to emulate Tim's answer below in MariaDB.

Comment: yes, thank you. @fadlikidd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `REGEXP_REPLACE` with a capture group:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Ctn/10Btl/100ml', '(\\d+)(\\D)', '\\1 \\2')
FROM yourTable;
```

Output: `Ctn/10 Btl/100 ml`

### Demo

Comment: @Zaw Your original question was tagged with MySQL, I believe.  MariaDB is _not_ the same thing as MySQL.  Check my slightly updated answer above.

Comment: Yes, I see.
Thank you.